# "stoi" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, string, integer, c++17, stoi

I have fixed it another way but I still want to know why **stoi** is not working here. This is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
std::string fakeBin(std::string str){
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
        int number=stoi(str[i]);
        std::cout<<number<<std::endl;
    }
    return "a";
}
int main()
{
fakeBin("12354234");
return 0;
}
```

while compiling

```
int number=stoi(str[I]);
```

I get this error:

> 'stoi' was not declared in this scope

Can you explain me why I am getting this error?

Comment: try `std::stoi`

Comment: Also, `std::stoi` takes a string, not a single character, which is what your `std::stoi(str[i])` is doing

Answer (score 1):

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function takes `std::string` as parameter. I suppose the question arises why the following code works but not yours.

```cpp
std::string s = "1";
int i = stoi(s);
```

The above code compiles fine without `std::` prefix because of [argument-dependent lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).
Basically, if a parameter is in a namespace, function resolution will be performed in that namespace as well.
In this case, `string` is in `std` namespace.

In your case, however, the provided parameter is a `char` reference.
Since no parameter is in a namespace, function resolution occurs only on global scope, thus it fails.

Function resolution succeeds when `std::stoi` is explicitly provided.
In that case, an [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is implicitly constructed from the `char` reference, and given as the first parameter to `stoi`.

Note that being able to avoid typing the namespace of a function with the help of ADL does not necessarily mean you should do that way.
Explicitly typing the namespace prevents such issues.
If nothing else, it informs the future reader about the origins of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You should write std:: stoi
or you can add a line " using namespace std; " just after the headerfile.

There are another mistake : stoi work only strings .here str[i] is a character . so you have to create a empty string variable  string s="";
and then s= s+ str[i] ; after this you can do std:: stoi(s);

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 0):

use `std::` before `stoi` (`std::stoi`)

`std::stoi` arguments are not true, so you are not using correct syntax, try to fix it as follows:

```
int       stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10 );
int       stoi( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10 );
```

and at least use `c++11`